# Saving quiz results to database

Tags: php, html, sql, pdo

I have created a multiple choice quiz/questionnaire. The questions and answers are pulling from the database and I have sessions setup on the webpage. At the minute the user can only print the webpage when they get their results.

I am using phpmyadmin and php for the quiz. I am currently pulling from one database table called questions with the fields, questionID, question, ansYes and ansNo.

```
<?
//Always start this first
session_start();
include ("dbConnect.php");

if ( isset( $_SESSION['user_email'] ) ) {
     //Grab user data from the database using user email

} else {
   // Redirect them to the login page
    header("login.php");
}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM questions";
$dbQuery = $db->prepare($sql);
$dbQuery->execute();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>List</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

  <style>


/* CSS animation */

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
    0% { 
        opacity:0; 
        transform: scale(0.6);
    }

    100% {
        opacity:100%;
        transform: scale(1);
    }
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
    0% { opacity:0; }
    100% { opacity:100%; }
}  
  </style>

 <?php include("navIn.php"); ?>


<body>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <br>

<?php

    /*Printing out questions*/

    if(!isset($_POST["submitForm"])) {
        echo "<form method='post' action='checklist.php'>";

       if (isset($_SESSION["first_name"])) {
            echo '<span style="color:#000000;position:left; left:1060px;">Hello '.$_SESSION["first_name"].'!<br></span>';
       }
        while($dbRow = $dbQuery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {


           echo"<div class=container-fluid text-center>";
            echo "<h4>" . $dbRow["question"] . "</h4>";
            echo "<h4><input type='radio' required name='" . $dbRow["questionID"] . "' value='Yes'> Yes <br></h4?";
            echo "<h4><input type='radio' required name='" . $dbRow["questionID"] . "' value='No'> No <br><br></h4>";
            echo "</div>";

        }
        echo "<input type='submit' name='submitForm' value='Submit'>";
        echo "</form>";

        echo"</div>";


    } else {

        if (isset($_SESSION["first_name"])) {
            echo '<span style="color:#000000;position:left; left:1060px;">Hello '.$_SESSION["first_name"].'!<br></span>';
       }
        /*printing out results from questions */
        echo"<div class=container-fluid text-center>";
        while($dbRow = $dbQuery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            if($_POST[$dbRow["questionID"]] == "Yes") {
                 echo '<h4 span style="color:blue;"> '.$dbRow["question"].'</span>';
                /*echo "<h4>" .$dbRow["question"]."<br></h4><br>";*/
                echo "<h4>" . $dbRow["ansYes"] . "</h4><br>";
            } else {
                echo '<h4 span style="color:blue;"> '.$dbRow["question"].'</span>';
         /*       echo "<h4>" .$dbRow["question"]."<br></h4><br>";*/
                echo "<h4>" . $dbRow["ansNo"] . "</h4><br>";


            }


        }
          echo"Click the button bellow to print this page!";
        echo'<br><form> <input type=button value="Print me!" onClick="javascript:window.print()"> </form>';
    echo"</div>";
    }

        ?>

</div>
</body>
 <?php include ("footer.php"); ?>
</html>
```

I would like to be able to save the users results so anytime they access checklist.php their results are there instead of having to print the page out.

Comment: Phpmyadmin is a tool used to manage the DB. It is not your DB

Comment: there are several facets to this - none of which have been addressed / included in the question &/or code really. To store the results you would need a new table that stores quiz id( perhaps ), question id, user id and answer. Is the storing of answers to be done when the form is submitted at the end of the quiz or for every answered question? Is the test for logged in users that will have a user id or is there another mechanism to remember users ( such as cookies )?

Comment: ok, I see `$_SESSION['user_email']` so presumably one of these question is answered

Comment: Do I need to create a new table to store the answers?(I'm relatively new to programming). The questions are all submitted at the end one all have been answered so the form loops until there is no more questions to answer then it is submitted using `echo "<input type='submit' name='submitForm' value='Submit'>";`

Comment: You need to connect the answers to the user, so if you create a new table to store the answers then you also need a field that connects the user account to this group of answers. If it were me, I would do it this way. But, if you wanted, you can also have a field in the users table that would store the quiz answers. Up to you.